Transition functions of the Dual bundle $E^*$
How can we prove that the transition functions of the dual bundle are the inverse transposes of those of the original bundle?
I know that the transition maps for the cotangent bundle $T^*M$ are the inverse transposes of those of the tangent bundle $TM$. This is easily seen by comparing how the components in two local trivialization corresponding to two different charts with nonempty intersection are related to each other.
However, I am struggling to prove that for any bundle $E$ with transition functions $\tau$, the dual bundle $E^*$ has transition functions $\tau^*=(\tau^{-1})^T$.
can someone provide a proof for the above claim?
Edit : following Ted Shifrin's comment, I wrote the following : let $(U,\Phi)$ and $(U',\Phi')$ be local trivializations with nonempty intersection, $\sigma_i(p)$ and $\sigma_i'(p)$ are the associated local frames, $\sigma_i^\ast(p)$ and  $\sigma_i'^\ast(p)$ the dual frames.
$$v \in E_p \rightarrow v=\sum_i c_i \sigma_i(p)  =\sum_j c'_j \sigma_j'(p) $$
$$c'_j=\sigma_j'^\ast(p)[v]=\sigma_j'^\ast(p)[\sum_i c_i \sigma_i(p)]=\sum_i c_i \sigma_j'^\ast(p)[\sigma_i(p)]$$
similarly
$$v^\ast \in {E_p}^\ast \rightarrow v^\ast=\sum_i c_i^\ast \sigma_i^\ast(p)  =\sum_j c'^\ast_j \sigma_j'^\ast(p)$$
$${c'_j}^\ast=v^\ast[\sigma'_j(p)]=(\sum c^\ast_i \sigma^\ast_i(p))[\sigma'_j(p)]=\sum c^\ast_i \sigma^\ast_i(p)[\sigma'_j(p)]$$
So my question basically boils down to how $\sigma_j'^\ast(p)[\sigma_i(p)]$ and $\sigma^\ast_i(p)[\sigma'_j(p)]$ are related.
more specifically, for any vector space $V$, and for bases $\{e_i\}$ and $\{e'_j\}$, with dual bases $\{e^\ast_i\}$ and $\{e'^\ast_j\}$, how are
$e^\ast_i[e'_j]$ and $e'^\ast_j[e_i]$ related to each other?
I realize this is more of a linear algebra question than one in smooth manifold theory, but I would appreciate any answer nonetheless.

There is no difference between the general case and the case of $E=TM$. Just write down $e'=\tau e$ and $\phi' = \sigma \phi$ (with $e,e'$ bases for $E$ and $\phi,\phi'$ corresponding dual bases for $E^*$), and then pair $\phi'$ with $e'$. Edit your post with your progress and ask a more specific question if you get stuck.

thank you very much. Certainly

How are you defining the dual bundle/have you proven it is actually a vector bundle? If so, this should be almost immediately true…

I believe we define each fiber separately, and use the fact that if the bundle charts are bijective maps to Euclidean spaces, whose restriction to each fiber is a vector space isomorphism, and the transition functions are continuous(resp. smooth), we have a continuous(resp. smooth) vector bundle. the crux of my problem is the last part.

The question is exercise 11.10 in Lee's introduction to smooth manifolds, and my issue is specifically the bold part of my original post.

@JohnDoe my point is that when checking the dual bundle is a vector bundle, you prescribe a trivializing atlas out of your vector bundle charts, and they should have the form you desire, because that’s pretty much the only option.

Not sure if this is correct, but suppose the two bases $\{e_i\}$ and $\{e'_j\}$ are related by an invertible matrix $B$ (change of basis matrix):
$$e_i=\sum_j B_{ji}e'_j \quad e'_j=\sum_i B^{-1}_{ij} e_i $$
then
$$e^\ast_i[e'_j]=e^\ast_i[\sum_k B^{-1}_{kj} e_k]=B^{-1}_{ij}$$
$$e'^\ast_j[e_i]=e'^\ast_j[\sum_k B_{ki}e'_k]=B_{ji}$$
which seem to be the inverse transposes of each other.
hope I hadn't mixed up the indices.

Thanks for the answer. And since matrix inversion and transposition is continuous(resp. smooth), the dual bundle  is continuous(resp. smooth) provided the original bundle has the same property.

I went through the same exercise a few months ago, I also proceeded exactly as you have done above. I wonder if there exists a more direct approach?

This is correct and I think the simplest approach.

@Deane does this not somehow assume that that the set $E^*$ is already a vector bundle? Otherwise how are we defining frame here?

@Chris, a smooth frame $(e_1, \dots, e_m)$ of $E$ uniquely determines a frame $(\epsilon^1, \dots, \epsilon^m)$ of $E^$, where for each $p \in M$, $(\epsilon^1(p), \dots, \epsilon^m(p))$ is the dual basis to $(e_1(p), \dots, e_m(p)).$ The vector bundle structure on $E^$ is the unique one for which the frame $(\epsilon^1, \dots, \epsilon^m)$ is smooth. Using the formulas in this answer, it is straightforward to verify that the transition functions for $E^*$ are smooth.

Let $E\rightarrow M$ be a vector bundle, with model fibre $V$, and $\{U_i,\phi_i\}$ a trivializing cover. As a set take:
$$E^*=\coprod_{x\in M}(E_x)^*$$
This comes equipped with a natural projection map, $\pi_{E^*}:E^*\rightarrow M$ such that:
\begin{align}
E^*_U:=\pi^{-1}_{E^*}(U)=\coprod_{x\in U}(E_x)^*
\end{align}
We define charts by:
\begin{align}
\phi_i^*:E^*_{U_i}&\longrightarrow U_i\times V^*\\
         \omega_x&\longmapsto (x, ((\phi_i)_x^{-1})^T\omega_x)
\end{align}
where $(\phi_i)_x$ is the linear isomorphism $E_x\rightarrow V$. These charts cover $M$, and are obvious bijections. We need only check that they are smoothly compatible, however this is again not difficult. Note that:
\begin{align}
(\phi_j^*)^{-1}(x,\omega)=(\phi_j)_x^T(\omega)
\end{align}
so:
\begin{align}
\phi_i^*\circ(\phi_j^*)^{-1}(x,\omega)=&(x,((\phi_i)_x^{-1})^T\circ(\phi_j)_x^T(\omega))\\
=&(x,((\phi_j)_x\circ (\phi_i^{-1})_x)^T(\omega))\\
=&(x,\phi_{ij}(x)^T\omega)
\end{align}
Since the transition functions $\phi_{ij}:U_i\cap U_j\rightarrow G(V)$ are smooth, and taking transpose is smooth, it follows that these charts are smoothly compatible.
It is now immediate that the transition functions for this vector bundle are the inverse transposes of the original bundle.
